Find the leading $1/L$ corrections to the magnetic field for a finite solenoid of length $L$
I found this exercise in the book Classical Electromagnetism in a Nutshell by Anupam Garg, on page 103 and chapter 24 about vector potential

I can find the magnetic field of the solenoid with length $L$ by Ampere's law
$$\vec{B}=\mu_0nI \hat{z} \;\; \text{inside the solenoid}$$
$$\vec{B}=0 \;\; \text{outside the solenoid}$$
But what does "the leading $1/L$ corrections" mean and how does it relate to vector potential?
My thought is that it might have something like multipole expansion.
I would really appreciate any help in understanding this exercise!

Let $S_L$ be a solenoid of length $L$ whose center is at the origin, and $S$ an infinite solenoid. The difference $S - S_L$, call it $S_{\overline{L}}$, is a pair of half-infinite solenoids: the parts of the infinite solenoid that are at a distance greater than $L/2$ from the origin.
And, similarly, $B_L = B - B_{\overline L}$, where $B_L$ is the field of the finite solenoid, $B$ is the field of the infinite solenoid, and $B_{\overline L}$ is the field produced by $S_{\overline L}$.
The field $B$ of the infinite solenoid is as you've said: $\mu_0 n I \hat{z}$ inside and 0 outside. But the field $B_L$ of the finite solenoid is not exactly $B$; it's $B - B_{\overline{L}}$. So $B_{\overline{L}}$ is a correction applied to $B$ to obtain the value of $B_L$.
$B_{\overline L}$ may be difficult or impossible to calculate exactly, but since it goes to zero as $L$ goes to infinity, it is reasonable to assume that $B_{\overline L}$ may be expressed as a power series in $1/L$. The lowest order term of that power series can be referred to as the leading correction.
It's possible to solve this problem using the interior multipole expansion, but I think the text wants you to solve it directly without any fancy techniques. In the text, Equation 24.10 gives the vector potential of $S_L$. By adjusting the inner integral to have bounds from $L/2$ to $\infty$ we can get the vector potential of $S_{\overline L}$:
$$
A_{\overline L} = \frac{2nIa\hat\varphi}{c}\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\varphi \int_{L/2}^\infty \mathrm{d}z (z^2 + s^2 - a^2 - 2as\cos\varphi)^{-1/2} \cos\varphi
$$
(I use $s$ for $r_\perp$, following Griffiths).
At this point, it's appropriate to use the generalized binomial expansion, $(x + a)^n = x^n + nx^{n-1} a + \frac{n(n-1)}{2} x^{n-2}a^2 + \ldots$. This gives us
$$
A_{\overline L} = \frac{2nIa\hat\varphi}{c}\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}\varphi \int_{L/2}^\infty \mathrm{d}z \left[z^{-1} - \frac{1}{2}z^{-3} (s^2 + a^2 - 2as\cos\varphi) + O(z^{-5})\right]\cos\varphi
$$
As before, the $z^{-1}$ term vanishes when we perform the integration over $\varphi$, so the $z^{-3}$ term is the leading contribution to the integral. We can then perform the integration without too much difficulty and get the leading order term in $A_{\overline L}$, of order $L^{-2}$ and from that obtain the leading order term in $B_{\overline L}$, also of order $L^{-2}$. This should be subtracted from the field of an infinite solenoid to get an approximation to the field of a finite solenoid of length $L$.
(It appears that the text uses Gaussian units, so be sure to report your answer in Gaussian units.)

Thank you very much for your answer! And is there any common trick to find the correction term in physics problems, or is it just intuitive?

@TommasoZouTommasoZou In general, for problems that involve finding an approximation for the electric field or magnetic field, you would use a multipole expansion for the scalar potential or vector potential. If the source is localized, you use an exterior multipole expansion. If the source extends to infinity and the observation point is near the origin, you use an interior multipole expansion.

OK, I understand. I really appreciate your help!

@TommasoZouTommasoZou Please remember to accept this answer if it solved your problem.
